Secure the vault password file in ansible
I have added the below line in ansible.cfg
vault_password_file = /var/tmp/password

I wanted to secure this file /var/tmp/password in such a way that only user ID (say abc12 user with group pcuser) has access. Others should not be able to read it. (not even root)
Below is what I tried:
Created the file with user abc12. Changed permission using root by below command
chown abc12:pcuser /var/tmp/password
chmod 600 /var/tmp/password

After this, permission is changed. But still root is able to read it.
I don't want root to read this file. Kindly advise.

root can read any file on the system.  Nothing you can do about it.

Should not have a password on disk anyway.  So, we store it in memory, in /run/user/${UID} with this script, store_vault_password.sh:
#!/bin/bash
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=$( mktemp -p /run/user/${UID} )
read -sp "Enter Vault Password: "
echo "${REPLY}" > ${ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE}
echo ${ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE}

Then, run that script like so:
export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=$( ./store_vault_pass.sh )

I got an error: export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=$( ./store_vault_password.sh )
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/run/user/0/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: No such file or directory
Enter Vault Password: ./store_vault_password.sh: line 4: ${ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE}: ambiguous redirect

User 0 is root.  Generally, you do not want to run Ansible as root.
